# Exchange 2016 Public Folder Automatic Reply Rule Not Working

Tags: exchange, public-folders, exchange-2016

I am trying to setup an automatic reply rule for a public folder in our Exchange 2016 environment.  I have created the folder, mail-enabled it, given myself send-as permissions and setup the rule in Outlook using the folder assistant but no replies are sent for either internal or external mails.  Where would I look to try and troubleshoot this?  I have checked the message tracking logs but I see no messages being sent with the folder's default reply email address.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to figure out what was the solution. I have public folder for which I need auto reply enabled. I have set myself as the owner of the PF and also granted send as permissions. Set up Auto reply using Folder assistant and I don't get the auto reply when I send a test email.

Comment: @SeshaChinta - No, was never able to get this working.